# What are the differences between put and add in Sembast?

Tags: database, flutter, nosql

Using Flutter package called Sembast.

What are the difference behaviors between these two commands?

`store.record(key).put(db, dataMap)`

and

`store.record(key).add(db, dataMap)`

Specifically about their behavior when there is an existing data.
Will they overwrite it? 
How does the 'merge' parameter works in the `put` method?

And also for any other differences if you have other pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per sembast documentation

```
  /// Create the record if it does not exist.
  ///
  /// Returns the key if inserted, null otherwise.
  Future<K> add(DatabaseClient databaseClient, V value) async
```

```
  /// Save a record, create if needed.
  ///
  /// if [merge] is true and the field exists, data is merged
  ///
  /// Returns the updated value.
  Future<V> put(DatabaseClient databaseClient, V value, {bool merge}) async
```

So basically add won't overwrite the record whereas put will

Edit:

1. Yes, exactly.
2. 

```
    if (merge == true) {
      record = txnGetRecordSync(txn, key);
      //if (record != null) {
      // Always merge to get rid of FieldValue.delete if any
      value = mergeValue(record?.value, value, allowDotsInKeys: true);
      //}
    } else {
      // Simple clone the calue
      value = cloneValue(value);
    }
```

and

```
/// Merge an existing value with a new value, Map only!
dynamic mergeValue(dynamic existingValue, dynamic newValue,
```

So merge works only for maps, if it works as you said, if not it will create a copy of an object, so the fields that don't exists in it will disappear.

Comment: 1. Does it mean that if the record exist, `add` won't do anything while `put` will overwrite it?

2. How does merge work? 
Is it like this: If merge = true: it overwrite the existing fields and create non-existing field. Thus after this process, the old and new fields are all existing at the same time.
If merge = false: it deletes all the fields then replace with the new fields. Thus, no old fields exist anymore afterwards.

Comment: I ran out of characters here, see the answer above

Comment: add: adds a new record and generate a new record key,
update: update an existing record,
put: will either create a new record with a user specified key or update a record